# jQuery change event sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have added an ajax validation to a textarea on my form, and initiate it using `onblur` in the html. However I have noticed that if I go to the submit the `onblur` event doesn't fire. Having read a lot of background I found a trick with `setTimeout` which I think ought to work by delaying the submit until after the blur. But I'm obviously doing something wrong or have misunderstood whats actually going on because its not working.

I have coded the following in  a document ready block in a file read into my page in the footer:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    setTimeout(() => this,0);
    $("#description").trigger('blur');
});
```

Can anyone see/explain my problem please?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you send text field value to the server with AJAX to validate it.

The function setTimeout wont help in your case. You have to wait for validation results first. And submit the form once validation result arrived.

So your code might look like this:

```
var isValid;

$("#description").on('blur', function(event){
    isValid = false;
    startValidation().then(function(){
        isValid = true;
        form.submit();
    });
});

$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(event){
    if (!isValid){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: The onblur calls a function which then does the ajax validation. If I simply click outside the textarea this works fine. The roblem is that if I maintain focus on the textarea and then click on the submit button the onblur fails to fire. I am trying to find a way to ensure the onblur runs before the form is submitted.

Comment: you can prevent default event processing by calling event.preventDefault()